# Chilkat Cryption/Decryption Issue Between PHP And .NET

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption, chilkat

I am trying to encrypt text/string in vb.net, pass to php script and decrypt there using chilkat crypt2 library for both coding language.

it works fine for non Unicode text with default charset :)

but when i try to crypt and decrypt Unicode text using "utf-8" charset it does not work..

php failed to decrypt it properly :( but if i decrypt the same encrypted text using vb.net it works as it should..

Raw/Plain Text:

> আস-সালামু-আলাইকুম ওয়া-রহমাতুল্লাহি ওয়া-বরকাতুহু

encrypted by vb.net function:

> PQ7i4/4kvMKR64jD4Y8umQJAR9+vAuhZ+bbdtZ8NzBJpPtNtL6c42lR0I1LAdeecI+D3n111CQQffHbMXL1xaccFQR0fqztmJawAMBL3N/VA4Lt45nRmnqc72tKwl0V3Fgayiysm0YsMW6N7hPkI6rqRn2smo9Xc8LEb4kfP/B/HkWhFP70mCsM7t8DUN2Sj

here the code follows:

vb.net code:

```
Public Function fCryption(strRaw As String, bolEncrypt As Boolean, strPass As String) As String
    Dim objCrypt As Chilkat.Crypt2
    Dim bolCryptReturn As Boolean
    Dim strHexKey As String
    Dim strReturn As String
    objCrypt = New Chilkat.Crypt2
    bolCryptReturn = objCrypt.UnlockComponent("Here Your Own Key Goes")
    objCrypt.Charset = "utf-8"
    objCrypt.CryptAlgorithm = "aes"
    objCrypt.CipherMode = "cbc"
    objCrypt.KeyLength = 256
    strHexKey = objCrypt.GenEncodedSecretKey(strPass, "hex")
    objCrypt.SetEncodedKey(strHexKey, "hex")
    objCrypt.EncodingMode = "base64"
    If bolEncrypt = True Then
        strReturn = objCrypt.EncryptStringENC(strRaw)
    Else
        strReturn = objCrypt.DecryptStringENC(strRaw)
    End If
    objCrypt.Dispose()
    objCrypt = Nothing
    Return strReturn
End Function
```

now the php function:

```
function fCryption($strRaw, $bolEncrypt, $strPass)
{
    $objCrypt = new CkCrypt2();
    $objCrypt->UnlockComponent('Here Your Own Key Goes');
    $objCrypt->put_Charset('utf-8');        
    $objCrypt->put_CryptAlgorithm('aes');
    $objCrypt->put_CipherMode('cbc');
    $objCrypt->put_KeyLength(256);
    $strHexKey = $objCrypt->genEncodedSecretKey($strPass, 'hex');
    $objCrypt->SetEncodedKey($strHexKey, 'hex');
    $objCrypt->put_EncodingMode('base64');
    if($bolEncrypt == true)
    {
        $strReturn = $objCrypt->encryptStringENC($strRaw);
    }
    else
    {
        $strReturn = $objCrypt->decryptStringENC($strRaw);
    }
    unset($objCrypt);
    return $strReturn;
}
```

and this is what php function return when i try to decrypt:

```
-- - -
```

so, i can't seems to find the cause why same function for same library works fine on vb.net but not on php :(

thanks in advance

best regards

Comment: any update? any one?

Comment: any help please?

Comment: still no one? no help?